# Configure third party DNS to Static Public Ip attached to AWS ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First of all, I am a beginner in this fields, so apologies If my questions is stupid or just too easy.

**What do we want to configure?** Well, we have a partnership with a website **wwww.partner.com**.

We have an application running on **elastic beanstal**k with an application load balancer. And we need to **provide** to our partner a **STATIC IP** for the to link w**[www.partner.com/ourcarpet](http://www.partner.com/ourcarpet)** to it.

To sum up, we want this architecture:

**DNS - [www.partner.com/ourcarpet](http://www.partner.com/ourcarpet) -------> OUR STATIC IP IN AWS
STATIC IP IN AWS -----> NLB --> EB**

I created a Network Load Balancer, and attract to it a STATIC IP. What I do not know is how to access this IP through HTTPS.

Am I using the correct approach? Can I link my Statis IP to a CNAME or A in a DNS outside of AWS?

Answer (score 1):

The "/ourcarpet" part of the URL is not visible for DNS.

The IP and other records can be set only for subdomain/domain names.

In that case [www.partner.com/ourcarpet](http://www.partner.com/ourcarpet) should be redirected to ourcarpet.partner.com (or another domain you control), so you can set the required IP.